# Can't manipulate operations in data.table

Tags: r

I have this data table:

```
> str(merged.tables_t)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  324326 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Store                    : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DayOfWeek                : int  1 1 3 7 5 5 4 2 6 7 ...
 $ Date                     : Factor w/ 942 levels "2013-01-01","2013-01-02",..: 903 315 366 832 298 214 395 491 908 384 ...
 $ Sales                    : int  4123 4017 0 0 4524 4776 4214 5992 2404 0 ...
 $ Customers                : int  491 509 0 0 531 545 493 628 303 0 ...
 $ Open                     : int  1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ Promo                    : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ StateHoliday             : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","a","b","c": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SchoolHoliday            : int  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ StoreType                : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Assortment               : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CompetitionDistance      : int  570 570 570 570 570 570 570 570 570 570 ...
 $ CompetitionOpenSinceMonth: int  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
 $ CompetitionOpenSinceYear : int  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ Promo2                   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Promo2SinceWeek          : int  13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ Promo2SinceYear          : int  2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 ...
 $ PromoInterval            : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Feb,May,Aug,Nov",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I need just need to create new variable which merge the tow columns  **CompetitionOpenSinceYear** and **CompetitionOpenSinceMonth**.

So first, I create new variable named CompetitionDate

```
merged.tables_t[,"CompetitionDate"]<-NA
```

Then, I modify the contains of this variable by this:

```
merged.tables_t[merged.tables_t[,19],as.character(as.Date(as.yearmon(with(merged.tables_t,sprintf("%d%02d",CompetitionOpenSinceYear,CompetitionOpenSinceMonth))))),]
```

It gives me that error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(merged.tables_t, , CompetitionDate =
>   as.character(as.Date(as.yearmon(with(merged.tables_t,  :    unused
>   argument (CompetitionDate =
>   as.character(as.Date(as.yearmon(with(merged.tables_t,
>   sprintf("%d-%02d", CompetitionOpenSinceYear,
>   CompetitionOpenSinceMonth))))))

Note that I get the needed result when I worked with data.frame:

```
> merged.tables_d$CompetitionDate<-as.character(as.Date(as.yearmon(with(merged.tables_d,sprintf("%d-%02d",CompetitionOpenSinceYear,CompetitionOpenSinceMonth)))))
```

The result sould be like this:

```
> head(merged.tables_d$CompetitionDate)
[1] "2007-11-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-01"
```

In fact, I need to work with data.table instead with data.frame because it's more faster in running time.

how can I get the same result using the data.table please?
thank you in advance

Comment: You can use `unite` from `tidyr` or `paste` from `base r`

Comment: @MKR, please give me complete answer using only **data.table** operations

Comment: Please share `dput(merged.tables_t)` and add output to your question. It will make easier for everyone to help

Comment: @MKR, you can see the result needed, and  `dput(merged.tables_t)` gives as result  many format like this  `1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,`

Comment: I have added an answer to help you. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on feedback from OP. An example has been added using `data.table` to concatenate two columns (for year and month) to form a `newcol` of type date. The OP intention is to use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

# Data 
dt <- data.table(CompetitionOpenSinceMonth = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 9, 10),
     CompetitionOpenSinceYear = c(2007, 2007,  2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006))

# Add another column using `:=` operator of data.table
dt[, newcol := as.yearmon(
       sprintf("%4d-%2d", CompetitionOpenSinceYear, CompetitionOpenSinceMonth))]

# Modified data.table
dt
#  CompetitionOpenSinceMonth CompetitionOpenSinceYear   newcol
#1:                        11                     2007 Nov 2007
#2:                        11                     2007 Nov 2007
#3:                        11                     2007 Nov 2007
#4:                        11                     2007 Nov 2007
#5:                        11                     2007 Nov 2007
#6:                        11                     2007 Nov 2007
#7:                         9                     2006 Sep 2006
#8:                        10                     2006 Oct 2006
```